# WiringPi Data is Available

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, driver, i2c

I am attempting to write a custom driver for the Adafruit LSM303 (https://www.adafruit.com/product/1120) so that I can write C++ code on a raspberry pi using this break out board. As I have been digging through the source for the Arduino driver (located here: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_LSM303DLHC/blob/master/Adafruit_LSM303_U.cpp) I find that code waits for the data to be ready before it is read: (line 87)

The following code is for Arduino using the Wire.h header for I2C access.

```
void Adafruit_LSM303_Accel_Unified::read()
{
 ...
  while (Wire.available() < 6);

  #if ARDUINO >= 100
    uint8_t xlo = Wire.read();
    uint8_t xhi = Wire.read();
    uint8_t ylo = Wire.read();
    uint8_t yhi = Wire.read();
    uint8_t zlo = Wire.read();
    uint8_t zhi = Wire.read();
  #else
    uint8_t xlo = Wire.receive();
    uint8_t xhi = Wire.receive();
    uint8_t ylo = Wire.receive();
    uint8_t yhi = Wire.receive();
    uint8_t zlo = Wire.receive();
    uint8_t zhi = Wire.receive();
  #endif    

  ...
}
```

Is it possible with in the wiringPi I2C library to wait for that data to be ready first? As in wait for the data to be ready, then read the data.

As a note, I am porting the Arduino code so that it works on a raspberry pi.

Comment: If I remember correctly, it returns -1 if no data is available. Is this correct?

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin A -1 means that there was an error.

Comment: @BenVoigt As far as I can tell there is no available() in the wiringPi library. I will add a comment to clarify that the code in the post is for Arduino.

Comment: @travis sorry I misunderstood the relationship of this code to yours.i thought you were calling it but actually you are porting it.

Comment: @BenVoigt You are correct. I am porting the code.